# Angular2 getting started issue

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to learn angular2 with type script and followed instructions as per https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I literally copy pasted everything and tried running. It just says 'Loading..'

Here is the log from console :

```
Error: " patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27

Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@//localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
ZoneTask/this.invoke@//localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29

Error loading //localhost:3000/app/main.js /:16:49
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple mistake. I had created file name as 'app.main.ts' instead of 'main.ts'